# How to fix module_layout in kernel-module?

Tags: linux, kernel, arm, kernel-module

I have compiled a new module into the Linux kernel.
Unfortunately, I can not load it.
The module is loaded on the remote machine. It was compiled by a cross compiler.

The problem is **module_layout**.
Because this new module was compiled from other sources than the kernel on the remote machine.

Is it possible to edit **module_layout**?

```
dmesg
[  620.716146] slip: no symbol version for module_layout

root@EmdeddedHost:/home modinfo ./slip.ko 
filename:       ./slip.ko
license:        GPL
alias:          tty-ldisc-1
srcversion:     10AE6D3498EFEFA9EF903F1
depends:        
vermagic:       3.12.10 SMP mod_unload modversions ARMv6 p2v8 
parm:           slip_maxdev:Maximum number of slip devices
```

Other module from remote machine (for comparison):

```
root@EmdeddedHost:/home modinfo /lib/modules/3.12.10-g8d69c4d-dirty/kernel/net/bridge/
bridge.ko 
filename:       /lib/modules/3.12.10-g8d69c4d-dirty/kernel/net/bridge/bridge.ko
license:        GPL
version:        2.3
alias:          rtnl-link-bridge
srcversion:     6D87CE67ABA06E938B02091
depends:        stp,llc
vermagic:       3.12.10-g8d69c4d-dirty SMP mod_unload modversions ARMv6 p2v
```

Comment: The real problem is that this module was compiled from other sources. Even if you fix the module_layout stuff, it will still crash, because symbols have different addresses. You need to compile modules using the kernel tree of the kernel where you want to use it.

Comment: I opened a .ko file (module) in hexedit. The file does not have a module_layout field.  Why?

Comment: I partially solved this problem... The solution was to issue a **make Image**, **make modules**, **make modules_install** commands. 
Unfortunately this did not completely solve my problem. Because I do not have a compatible **linux-headers** package/files. `[153815.620337] slhc: disagrees about version of symbol kmem_cache_alloc
[153815.627389] slhc: Unknown symbol kmem_cache_alloc (err -22)
[153815.635460] slhc: disagrees about version of symbol kmalloc_caches ...
`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/14627/no-symbol-version-for-module-layout-when-trying-to-load-usbhid-ko